# What is the right file signature?

Tags: file-format

I want to have a correct table of file signatures. I found two sites that have a big table of file signatures but when comparing those two, I saw that there was a different.

For example, [on this site](https://zims-en.kiwix.campusafrica.gos.orange.com/wikipedia_en_all_nopic/A/List_of_file_signatures), the 3gp file signature is listed as `66 74 79 70 33 67`.

[On this other site](https://filesignatures.net/index.php?page=search&search=3GP&mode=EXT), the file signature of 3gp is as following: `00 00 00 14 66 74 79 70`.

What is the right one? If I would check a 3gp file, what would be the first bytes of this file?

Comment: Note: `66 74 79 70 33 67` at offset 4 and `00 00 00 14 66 74 79 70` at offset 0 are not contradictory.

Comment: The first link seems to be an (outdated?) copy of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How does this offset work? Would be the first bytes of my 3gp file start with `00 00 ...` or with `66 74 ...` or could it be both?

Comment: You should probably start with the definitions used by TrID https://mark0.net/soft-trid-deflist.html

Comment: Offset tells you how many bytes you need to skip. `00 00 00 14 66 74 79 70 33 67` at offset 0 matches your both signatures.

Comment: @GantendoThats some big list. But 3pg is listed there as just `00 00 00`? https://file-extension.net/seeker/file_extension_3gp

Comment: If you check the Wikipedia link 3gp is listed as 66 74 79 70 33 67  starting at offset 4. The bytes before that are probably zero for padding, but they are not used as a file signature.

Comment: The 00 00 00 you see is the start of the header hexdump, not the signature itself

Comment: One last question, what does the offsets `end–512`, `0, any` and `0x8001` mean?

Comment: the location of the end of the file minus 512 bytes. `0, any` means at the start or anywhere in the file.

Comment: @sirzento It means that the signature (usually) occurs at byte offset 32769 (0x8001),
34817 (0x8801), or 36865 (0x9001). Those are the decimal version of those hexadecimal numbers